# Javascript Module Pattern - difference

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am aware of javascript module pattern but I use two types of module patterns and would like to know the difference between them from an architectural perspective.

```
// PATTERN ONE
var module = (function() {
  var _privateVariable = '';

  var _privateMethod = function() {
    var _this = this;
    // private method def
    // can use _this._privateVariable
    console.log('Inside a private method!');
  };

  var publicMethod = function() {
    var _this = this;
    // public method def
    // can use _this._privateVariable
    // can call _privateMethod();
  };

  return {
    publicMethod: publicMethod
  };
})();

// PATTERN TWO
var module = (function() {
  var wrapper = {
    _privateVariable: '',

    _privateMethod: function() {
      var _this = this;
      // private method def
      // can use _this._privateVariable
      console.log('Inside a private method!');
    },

    publicMethod: function() {
      var _this = this;
      // public method def
      // can use _this._privateVariable
      // can call _privateMethod();
    },
  };

  return {
    publicMethod: wrapper.publicMethod
  };
})();
```

Both these patterns seem to do the same thing for me

1. Is there a significant difference in using either of them?
2. Should one of these patterns be avoided?
3. Is there a better way to use either of them?

Comment: The only difference is that you return the methods result instead of the method itself in version 2... And i prefer the second as its shorter and better structured.

Comment: keep in mind you can also use es modules, but you'll need babel for that

Comment: Your second snippet does *call* `publicMethod()` instead of "exporting" it.

Comment: `var _this = this;` is not meaningful in either of your patterns. You should just refer to the variables directly (in the first snippet), or to properties of `wrapper` (in your second snippet).

Comment: @Bergi I edited the code where I made a method call instead of export =)

Comment: OK, thanks, now the comments "*can use `_this._privateVariable`*" and "*can call `_privateMethod();`*" are definitely false

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is no difference between the two patterns you've mentioned. Only difference I see is that the second pattern uses `wrapper` as an extra variable which can be avoided.

Considering other cases, where you might want to return a complex object rather than the current one, then the second pattern is very useful,

for eg.

```
var wrapper = {
_privateVariable: '',

_privateMethod: function() {
  var _this = this;
  console.log('Inside a private method!');
},

publicMethod: function() {
  var _this = this;
},

publicMethod2: function() {
  var _this = null;
},

publicMethod3: function(default) {
  var _this = default;
},
};

return {
   publicMethod: wrapper
};
```